# I have a batch file. When I run it I want it to open files using another batch file. But how?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command

So I have a batch file that inserts frames in animated gif files using ffmpeg, lets call it "batch1".
Unfortunately that batch file is only capable to do 1 gif file, so that means I cannot drop (lets say) 25 gif files on it and have it do its magic. As I have no clue how to fix that I thought maybe I could make another batch file, lets call it "batch2" and use that to open files using "batch1". Something like this:

```
batch1.bat F:\_FFMPEG_\bin\01.gif
timeout /T 25
move F:\_FFMPEG_\bin\_*.gif F:\_FFMPEG_\bin\_FILES_\
batch1.bat F:\_FFMPEG_\bin\02.gif
timeout /T 25
move F:\_FFMPEG_\bin\_*.gif F:\_FFMPEG_\bin\_FILES_\
batch1.bat F:\_FFMPEG_\bin\03.gif
timeout /T 25
move F:\_FFMPEG_\bin\_*.gif F:\_FFMPEG_\bin\_FILES_\
```

and so on, and so on, until the 25th gif file.

batch1.bat takes the gif file, inserts overlays on certain frames and saves it with a _ in front of the filename. The timeout is because it takes some time to insert the overlays in the gif files, usually 20 seconds.

But.. As soon as I run the file I get this error:

*'batch1.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.*

When I run the commands in a CMD window it works just fine.

Can anyone please enlighten me and tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you perhaps executing the base batch file with RUNAS Administrator from the context menu?  Personally I think you are going about this all wrong.  If you show us what is inside each batch file we could easily condense your code into one batch file and make it much more dynamic.

Comment: You should be using `Call "batch1.bat" "filepath\file.ext"`, and should as a result of using the correct command, then be able to remove each of your `timeout` lines. _You just have to be sure that `batch1.bat` does not end with `Exit`._ You should also be aware that you're not providing a path to `batch1.bat`, so it must be located in the current directory at the time it is `call`ed.

Comment: @Squashman I seriously have no idea what I am doing, this thing I am trying all came from a bit of google-ing. What I would be perfect is that I would be able to just drop multiple (lets say 25) gif files on the following batch file and that it would do one after the other by itself. This is the batch file in question: https://pastebin.com/28vcbnNs

Comment: @Jale, please take the [tour]. Then read [ask] a good question and then provide a [mcve] of **ALL** the code you are using.

Comment: @Squashman Will do most certainly. Shall I remove this question and better word a new one with examples?

Comment: @Jale Use the [edit] link to update your question with relevant information.

Comment: Based upon your intention of dropping files onto `batch2.bat`, you could probably just change it to a single line: `@For %%G In (%*) Do @Call "batch1.bat" "%%~G" && Move /Y "%%~dpG_*.gif" "%%~dpG_FILES_"`. *…and obviously the `.\_FILES_` directory would have to already exist*.

Comment: @Compo THAT WORKED! OMG I am so happy, thank you very very much!!! 

Answer (score 0):

For more information please visit this question [How to execute a batch script (child.bat) from a batch file (parent.bat)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67068116/how-to-execute-a-batch-script-child-bat-from-a-batch-file-parent-bat-origin)

In order for control to be passed back to the parent batch file, the child batch file must be invoked with the `CALL` command.

```
CALL batch1.bat F:\_FFMPEG_\bin\01.gif
move F:\_FFMPEG_\bin\_*.gif F:\_FFMPEG_\bin\_FILES_\

CALL batch1.bat F:\_FFMPEG_\bin\02.gif
move F:\_FFMPEG_\bin\_*.gif F:\_FFMPEG_\bin\_FILES_\

CALL batch1.bat F:\_FFMPEG_\bin\03.gif
move F:\_FFMPEG_\bin\_*.gif F:\_FFMPEG_\bin\_FILES_\
```

**For Example**

child.bat

```
@echo off
echo Child Batch File is running !!!
echo Doing some Important Child Batch Stuff here . . . .
echo ✔ Child Batch Completed it. Voila !!
echo Now exiting Child.bat
```

parent.bat

```
@echo off
echo Parent Batch File is running !!!
echo Doing some Important Stuff here . . . .
echo ✔ Completed it. Voila !!
echo Now running Child.bat . . .

echo -------------------------------------------------------

child.bat   
rem Comment: Some how below statements are not executing
echo -------------------------------------------------------

echo ✔ Completed it. Voila !!
echo I believe all the this are complete.
echo I am now exiting.
```

This will run:

```
C:\Users\abc> parent.bat

Parent Batch File is running !!!
Doing some Important Stuff here . . . .
✔ Completed it. Voila !!. .
Now running Child.bat . . .
-------------------------------------------------------
Child Batch File is running !!!
Doing some Important Child Batch Stuff here . . . .
✔ Child Batch Completed it. Voila !!
Now exiting Child.bat

C:\Users\abc>
```

Wont execute other statements.

#### TO correct this Use `CALL` :

child.bat wont change

```
@echo off
echo Child Batch File is running !!!
echo Doing some Important Child Batch Stuff here . . . .
echo ✔ Child Batch Completed it. Voila !!
echo Now exiting Child.bat
```

parent.bat use `CALL` to execute *.bat script

```
@echo off
echo Parent Batch File is running !!!
echo Doing some Important Stuff here . . . .
echo ✔ Completed it. Voila !!
echo Now running Child.bat . . .

echo -------------------------------------------------------

rem Comments: CALL will execute the .bat and return the cmd context back to the parent.bat for further execution.
CALL child.bat   

echo -------------------------------------------------------

echo ✔ Completed it. Voila !!
echo I believe all the this are complete.
echo I am now exiting.
```

Output:

```
Parent Batch File is running !!!
Doing some Important Stuff here . . . .
✔ Completed it. Voila !!. .
Now running Child.bat . . .
-------------------------------------------------------
Child Batch File is running !!!
Doing some Important Child Batch Stuff here . . . .
✔ Child Batch Completed it. Voila !!
Now exiting Child.bat
-------------------------------------------------------
Completed it. Voila !!
echo I believe all the this are complete.
echo I am now exiting.
```

Some References:

[CALL | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/call)

Answer (score 0):

Solution and correct answer was given by user Compo.

```
@For %%G In (%*) Do @Call "batch1.bat" "%%~G" && Move /Y "%%~dpG_*.gif" "%%~dpG_FILES_"
```

This is all what it needed and it works flawlessly now!