# How to execute a batch script (child.bat) from a batch file (parent.bat)? Original Question(C# run Pip install in Venv programmatically)

Tags: batch-file, cmd, method-call

My original question was "C# run Pip install in Venv programmatically" but it turns out there was no issue with C# code or the Pip thing. But with the Batch Script. SO first is the edited question to help others and then my original question for just a record.

## Run a Batch script with a command to run another Batch file.

**child.bat**

```
@echo off
echo Child Batch File is running !!!
echo Doing some Important Child Batch Stuff here . . . .
echo ✔ Child Batch Completed it. Voila !!
echo Now exiting Child.bat
```

**parent.bat**

```
@echo off
echo Parent Batch File is running !!!
echo Doing some Important Stuff here . . . .
echo ✔ Completed it. Voila !!
echo Now running Child.bat . . .

echo -------------------------------------------------------

child.bat

// Comment: Some how below statements are not executing
echo -------------------------------------------------------

echo ✔ Completed it. Voila !!
echo I believe all the this are complete.
echo I am now exiting.
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\abc> parent.bat

Parent Batch File is running !!!
Doing some Important Stuff here . . . .
✔ Completed it. Voila !!. .
Now running Child.bat . . .
-------------------------------------------------------
Child Batch File is running !!!
Doing some Important Child Batch Stuff here . . . .
✔ Child Batch Completed it. Voila !!
Now exiting Child.bat

C:\Users\abc>
```

Where are the other `parent.bat` echo commands.

Expected Output:

```
Parent Batch File is running !!!
Doing some Important Stuff here . . . .
✔ Completed it. Voila !!. .
Now running Child.bat . . .
-------------------------------------------------------
Child Batch File is running !!!
Doing some Important Child Batch Stuff here . . . .
✔ Child Batch Completed it. Voila !!
Now exiting Child.bat
-------------------------------------------------------
Completed it. Voila !!
echo I believe all the this are complete.
echo I am now exiting.
```

## Old Question for just a record

I have a C# application and it uses some python scripts. To run the python scripts I need to have some dependencies. So i created a batch file that creates a VENV. But it never runs PIP INSTALL COMMAND.

#### C# Code to run multiple cmd statements. It creates a batch file.

```
        public void abc() {
            var batFileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), $"{Guid.NewGuid()}.bat");
            using (var batFile = new StreamWriter(batFileName))
            {
                var pythonPath = Path.Combine(LocalAppData, ProjectGuid, HolocronFolders["HolocronPython"]);
                var venv = Path.Combine(LocalAppData, ProjectGuid, HolocronFolders["HolocronVenv"]);
                batFile.WriteLine($"{pythonPath}\\python.exe -m venv {venv}");
                batFile.WriteLine($"{venv}\\Scripts\\activate.bat");
                batFile.WriteLine($"pip install rich"); //  Not running in venv
            }
            var process = new Process();
            var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "cmd.exe",
                Arguments = $"/C {batFileName}"
            };
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();
            File.Delete(batFileName);
        }
```

#### batch file created

```
Path_to_python\python.exe -m venv path_to_venv_folder
Path_to_venv_folder\Scripts\activate.bat
pip install rich            --//-- Comments: Not running in Venv. Actually not running at all.
```

#### cmd output:

```
c:\user\abc> Path_to_python\python.exe -m venv path_to_venv_folder
c:\user\abc> Path_to_venv_folder\Scripts\activate.bat
(path_to_venv_folder) c:\user\abc>
```

Comment: This is a pretty common issue.  I think we answer this question at least a few times a month.  When a batch file runs another batch file, in order for control to be passed back to the parent batch file, the child batch file must be invoked with the `CALL` command. `CALL activate.bat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When another batch file is executed from a command or a script the context is changed to that batch file and the parent file commands are lost somehow.
As [@Squashmas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1417694/squashman) says "In order for control to be passed back to the parent batch file, the child batch file must be invoked with the `CALL` command"

child.bat

```
@echo off
echo Child Batch File is running !!!
echo Doing some Important Child Batch Stuff here . . . .
echo ✔ Child Batch Completed it. Voila !!
echo Now exiting Child.bat
```

parent.bat

```
@echo off
echo Parent Batch File is running !!!
echo Doing some Important Stuff here . . . .
echo ✔ Completed it. Voila !!
echo Now running Child.bat . . .

echo -------------------------------------------------------

rem Comments: CALL will execute the .bat and return the cmd context back to the parent.bat for further execution.
CALL child.bat   

echo -------------------------------------------------------

echo ✔ Completed it. Voila !!
echo I believe all the this are complete.
echo I am now exiting.
```

## Old Answer for the record.

So the commands in the batch script should be:

```
Path_to_python\python.exe -m venv path_to_venv_folder
CALL Path_to_venv_folder\Scripts\activate.bat
pip install rich
```

`CALL activate.bat` will pass the cmd context back to the parent batch file.

What I did here is almost the same as using CALL. I don't recommend this. Use CALL.

```
Path_venv_folder\Scripts\activate.bat && pip install rich
```

After the first command is run due to the `&&` operator context is still with the parent invoked cmd as the command is yet complete and the cmd context is not passed to the child batch script in this case `activate.bat` until the whole command is executed and `true` or equivalent is returned.

The output using `CALL` is:

```
c:\user\abc> Path_to_python\python.exe -m venv path_to_venv_folder
c:\user\abc> CALL Path_to_venv_folder\Scripts\activate.bat
(path_to_venv_folder) c:\user\abc> pip install rich
installing rich..............
installing colorama....................
blah blah blah

(path_to_venv_folder) c:\user\abc>
```

The output using `&&` is:

```
c:\user\abc> Path_to_python\python.exe -m venv path_to_venv_folder
c:\user\abc> CALL Path_to_venv_folder\Scripts\activate.bat && pip install rich
installing rich..............
installing colorama....................
blah blah blah

(path_to_venv_folder) c:\user\abc>
```

Notice the `venv` activated cmd is shown after the `pip` command is executed. Although the `pip` ran in context of the `venv` it is not accurate and so I don't recommend it.

PS: I am not a batch script expert so please correct me if I am wrong. I will improve it asap.

**Some References:**

[CALL | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/call)